# How do I get the ID of iframe's parent div?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that looks like this:

```
 <div class="myclass" id="div1"><iframe id="frame1" src="myiframe.html"></div>
 <div class="myclass" id="div2"><iframe id="frame2" src="myiframe.html"></div>
```

In my `iframe`, I need to know the id of the div of its parent node, but I don't know how.
I searched for a solution without jquery but all I found was something with `getElementById` stuff and I am actually searching for the id.

Can someone help me?

Comment: To clarify: you are going to run the Javascript inside the `<iframe>`, not the container of it?

Comment: yes, i want to run the javascript inside the <iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that, as far as your JS code inside the iFrame is concerned, the window *is* the iFrame, and the document is the content of that iFrame. Here's a little function that should work for you, in order to the parent's document:

```
var parentDoc = window;
while(parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent)
{
    parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
}
parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
var iFrames = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var divs = [];
for(var i=0;i<iFrames.length;i++)
{
    divs.push(iFrames[i].parentNode);//assuming the first parent is the div
}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: that works, great. the problem now is that the website i embed it from and the iframe are from different domains. :S

Comment: That doesn't really make a difference when it comes to JS... what problem are you trying to do, that makes this a problem?

Comment: I solved my problem by passing the ID by through the controller. Although thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("div id")

var parentDivOfIfame1 = $("#frame1", parent.document).parent();
```

Comment: Safari says: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'parent.document.getElementById')`
Chrome says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined`